# Compile EXPAT to statically-linked .a on Windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw, expat-parser

I am writing C program on Windows with MingW and want to use EXPAT XML library. I want to compile my program statically, so I need static .a library.

Is there any way to compile EXPAT to .a static, independent library on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you download official releases from [Expat Sourceforge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/) you won't be able to compile and install the library with MSYS nor MinGW. You will need an installation of CygWin to configure, make and install.

To compile and install native MinGW library you need modified version of `configure` script and `libtool`. Just download expat [source tarball provided by MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/expat/expat-2.0.1-1/expat-2.0.1-1-mingw32-src.tar.gz/download) instead of main original expat. Also you may want use [precompiled binaries instead](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/expat/expat-2.0.1-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded and built the package, it appears to have made a static library by default.  What's not working for you?

Comment: What is your 'build'? Because I have no cygwin so I can't build the linux source, which use autoconf, and no MSVC, so I can't build the windows source.

And I need .a, not .lib, .dll or .so.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Despite no error occurs, MinGW's ld refuses to generate any .la nor .dll libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **dynamic** and **static** version of expat using MinGW package installer:

1. **open** a *cmd* or *shell*
2. **update** the package list: **`mingw-get update`** *(optional)*
3. **install** the package(s) you need:

   - *dynamic (.dll):* **`mingw-get install expat`**
   - *static (.a and .dll.a):* **`mingw-get install libexpat`**
4. depending on what you've chosen, you'll **find** ...

   - *dynamic* lib in `<your mingw>/bin`, file: `libexpat-1.dll`
   - *static* lib in `<your mingw>/lib`, files: `libexpat.a`, `libexpat.dll.a`, `libexpat.la`

**Package overview:**

- package **expat**: Dynamic `libexpat-1.dll` incl. *xmlwf.exe*
- package **libexpat**: Static `libexpat.a`, `libexpat.dll.a` and `libexpat.la`